# How to Remove a parent of an empty tag jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple data which i inserted into an html tag. Some of the tags are empty while some are filled with details. What i want is how do i remove the parent of the ones that are empty, this is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="row order-info">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h6 class="nameDiv">Hello this is nice</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <h6 class="proId"></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <h6 class="proP">testing. testing</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
removeEmpty();

function removeEmpty() {
    if($(".order-info div h6").text().length < 1) {
        $(this).closest(".col-12").remove();
    }
}
```

Please What am i doing wrong

Comment: You need to use `.each()` to iterate over them; your code will combine all their texts into one long string.

Comment: You are using ``$(this)``. Try ``$(".order-info div h6").closest('.col-12').remove()``. Just to elaborate a bit more: ``this`` will refer to the scope of function and not the element you are targeting, that's the reason it is not working.

Comment: @SachinSingh That won't test for empty

Comment: @SachinSingh It removed all the tags so it didn't work

Comment: I think when the element is empty .text() will return white space which will pass your conditional statement.

Comment: It won't work unless you iterate over each element: https://jsfiddle.net/rk5a4qsy/

Comment: You also have to use ``each`` as @ChrisG suggested. Something like ``$(".order-info div h6").each(function () { /* Place your logic inside here */ })``.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me out

Comment: I sure hope those `<h6>` elements come after an `<h5>` somewhere and that the `<h5>` comes after an `<h4>` and so on. Don't use headings because of how they style your text. That's what CSS is for. HTML is for semantics and structure.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.order-info .col-12').has('h6:empty').remove();
```

This code will remove those elements of class `.col-12` that contain an empty `h6` element.

Comment: all the tags was still removed

Comment: Which tags—you mean all `.col-12` tags? I ran the code in my browser and it works fine.

Comment: Why did you accept the other answer, if I may ask? Do you prefer seven lines of code and manual looping over a single line of simple, declarative code?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to add both as the correct answer but I can only choose one but in my code I used yours since its shorter

Answer (score 0):

You're not iterating using the css selector.

Try this function:

```
function removeEmpty() {
    $(".order-info div h6").each(function(elem){
        if($(this).html().length < 1) {
            $(this).closest(".col-12").remove();
        }  
    })
}
```